# How to deploy swagger generated spring code (Tomcat)

Tags: spring, tomcat, swagger

I used the example given by SwaggerCodeGen to create a Server via SpringBoot.
I build the project with maven and run it local. Everythings works fine.

Now I want to deploy this project on a tomcat (version 7).
So I changed the packing from jar to war

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and moved the *.war file to tomcat\webapps folder

I tried to run

> localhost:8080/app

which return an 404

same with

> localhost:8080/app/swagger-ui.html 
>   localhost:8080/v1/app/ 
>   localhost:8080/v1/app/api-docs

Unfortunatly, I have got no experience with tomcat. 
The Project doesn't contain a web.xml. Is it necessary?
Do I need to create a Servlet?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your POM you need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Your SpringBoot Application should also look like this:

```
public class SpringBootServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootServiceApplication .class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootServiceApplication .class);
    }

}
```